# How to fix an old ubuntu boot error (kernel panic) from new installed ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

A few months ago I installed an **Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS** on my laptop (ASUS K43sv ,SSD 128GB). suddenly it couldn't boot anymore. and unfortunately there are not any other versions of kernels to found out them in grub mode. At last I decide to install another ubuntu alongside of that, now I can see those old files and paths of my old unbootable ubuntu.

[image]

So I have a question to ask How can I repair my old ubuntu from this new one? any solution like using **boot repair** software or **Grub Customiser** ?

I tried from grub and selecting **Advanced options for Ubuntu** but as I said before did not work. and tells me about this Error: **Kernel panic - not syncing**

[image]

Comment: Hello SadeQ. Can you post more information? machine info. error logs or screenshots. To help you recover that installation we need to understand whats wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO (unless 21.10)
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: @jpbrain I edited my question. please review it again.

Comment: hi @SadeQdigitALLife. Can you also post the output of "ls -l /boot" of that disk and the partitions where boot Ubuntu are installed? We will try to fix it.